# Java - Lucene - How to filter a search using an array of docids

Tags: java, lucene

I would like to know how to restrict the search of a query within a set of docids. So far, I am able to output a list of the docids from a search to an array (or text file). I would like to search for other terms but limiting the results within this list of documents.

Please be descriptive in your answer considering I am a java newbie. I dont understand most of the javadocs covering the filter/filtereddocidset/docidset in the lucene website.

Thank you very much

Comment: why you need to filter your results by docid? or docid is an ordinary field of your documents?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom [`Collector`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Collector.html) (see Javadoc example on how this is done). In the `collect` method, you would **only** set the `BitSet` flag for the matching `docId`s which, I assume, you obtain somehow externally.